# Learning Rust: error: `x` does not live long enough

Tags: rust

In [this Rust book](https://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v1.25/arch/amd64_ubuntu1404/share/doc/rust/html/book/first-edition/references-and-borrowing.html):

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = 5;
    let y = &mut x;

    *y += 1;

    println!("{}", x);
}
```

In this case, the compiler can easily know that y has already finished its job since there is no more code after the `println`, so print x is safe. Why does it still complain?

In bellow code snippet:

```
let y: &i32;
let x = 5;
y = &x;

println!("{}", y);
```

The compiler should know that the consequent `println` is safe and allow it; so after this line, I can do `y = &z;` reusing y.

Comment: [On Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=60f2cfb3a75cb274d3d40427e5d3d543) the first code snippet compiles and runs just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are reading a very old version of the Rust book, from before *non-lexical lifetimes* were introduced. Back then, the compiler would indeed reject such code — it did not look at when the references were no longer actually in use, only where the scope of the variable `y` ends. Now, in current Rust, the same code is accepted.

You should use [the current, official version of the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html).